# Target Preprocessor Macros are ignored by the preprocessor in Xcode

Tags: xcode, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I added `TEST=1` in the `Preprocessor Macros` section of the project target's `Build Settings`, and whenever I use it in code, the preprocessor thinks it's not defined.

1. <kbd>alt</kbd> + click on it shows a question mark
2. The syntax coloring doesn't work well
3. The syntax autocomplete doesn't work well

For example, having:

```
#if TEST

// a

#else

// b

#endif
```

has this behavior:

1. Syntax coloring only works for `// b`
2. Syntax autocomplete only works for `// b`

This is because the preprocessor can't find `TEST` (even if it's defined as `1`, as I previously stated) so it treats it as being `false`.

Is there any way to solve these problems?

**Edit:**

My use case is related to multiple Project Targets. So, say that the initial target is named `First`, which has the `TEST` preprocessor macro defined with value `1`.

If I create another project target named `Second` with no preprocessor macros defined and want to add some code for it only if `TEST` is `0` (`false`/not defined), I'll put it in the `#else` block (`// b`).

Knowing that syntax coloring and autocomplete works for `// b`, it looks like it works ok, but if I change the current target to the `First` one (*pun intended*) and even build it, it still works as `Second` is selected.

Comment: if you build the project, preprocessor will detect the compile time flags and will show coloring and autocomplete. have you tried that?

Comment: Of course I built the project.

Comment: Did you do it for both debug and release? It works at my end.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Build Configurations. I updated my question.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to do it like this in Swift, you should add a `User-Defined` setting named `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` in your `Build Settings` like this:

[image: OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS user-defined setting]

And then in your code you type:

```
#if TEST1

// Debug

#endif

#if TEST2

// Release

#endif
```

I don't know why you need this, but it may be interesting to look into native Xcode Target, to use specific behavior for multiple apps with same root project. If this is what you want, you should look into an article this: [AppCoda using Targets with Xcode](http://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/).

Answer (score 5):

Just go to target->Edit Scheme -> Run -> Info and check the Build Configuration. Now while adding the Preprocessor Macros in build setting just make sure you are adding the macro for correct build configuration and correct target.

[image: ≈]

I tried by adding for both debug and release build as above for my target App (Test-ObjectiveC). So when i tried below code with this setting, u can see the syntax color accordingly.

[image]

Comment: And what happens when you cmd + click it?

Comment: @lulian not sure what you want to check there with cmd + click.

Comment: I was just wondering if it knows to open the `Build Settings` or if it's showing the question mark as in my example. There might be other settings of my big project that interfere with this. I'll try testing it myself in a new project and try to find if the problem is caused by one of my settings.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make it work by setting "Target->Build Settings->All->Swift Compiler - Custom Flags -> Active Compilation Conditions".

XCode version 12.3